# My old SO account was registered with my previous work email

Tags: support, user-accounts

My old user was registered with my previous work email, can it be deleted and the questions taken to my new account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the steps here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Once the merge is complete (either automatically or with our help), you can go back to "my logins" and remove the old credentials.