# How can I prove ownership of an account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, merge-accounts

After I followed the steps from the answer: [My old SO account was registered with my previous work email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146367/my-old-so-account-was-registered-with-my-previous-work-email) I completed the form and received an email that said:

> If you are unable to log into one of them, *complete as much as you can with the verifications and I will see if I can verify your ownership between the accounts*.

What verification is needed, I don't have access to the old email, actually the old email is no more valid, what do I know is:

- the email used to create that account and the fact that is no longer valid;
- the IPs with which I browsed SO at that time;
- the fact that I deleted the old email gravatar associated with the old account around the same time I created this SO account I'm writing now with.

Is this enough to prove my ownership of that account?

Answer (score 2):

You should reply to the email with the information you have which you believe verifies that the account is in fact yours. If you do not supply enough, I would imagine the individual emailing you will let you know.

Beyond that advice, I'm not sure how you think the community can help you in this endeavor.

Comment: I didn't got a reply but I imagine the volume of request is huge, and that's why I asked, to get a second opinion know if what I have is enough.